# Set up virtual directory as root in asp.net app windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have a server with a couple of sites on it and I have an asp.net app in a virtual directory off default.

What I'd like to be able to do is use absolute paths (\include, \css) on the site since it will be migrated to its own site and I don't want to mess with relatives.

Is there a way to set up the virtual dir to be 'root' as far as the asp.net app is concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your going to be able to use absolute paths in the application if it is currently installed in a virtual directory and still expect things to work.

Typically we use the tilde (~) for paths which allows .Net to determine the correct location whether it's in a virtual directory or off of the root.

For example:
Response.Redirect("~/SomeDir/SomePage.aspx")

If the site is deployed at http://myhost/myapp/ then .Net will translate that to "/myapp/SomeDir/SomePage.aspx"

If the site is deployed at http://myhost/ then .Net will translate it to "/SomeDir/SomePage.aspx"

Bear in mind that the tilde only works on tags with the runat="server" attribute set.  So you would need to add that to any normal html tags like `<script src=...`